# Acumatica API login unauthorized after upgrade to 6.1

Tags: authentication, acumatica

We just recently upgraded our Acumatica instance to Version 6.10.0680.  I was using the contract based API on our previous instance (V 5.30.2489) to login to the API and create sales orders using this code:

```
using (DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient(binding, address))
{
    try {
        //Login to Acumatica API
        await client.LoginAsync(_acumaticaUid, _acumaticaPwd, _acumaticaCompany, null, null);

        //Create a sales order with the specified values
        SalesOrder newOrder = (SalesOrder)await client.PutAsync(orderToBeCreated);

        client.Logout();

        return newOrder;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //order addition to Acumatica failed, update the order status in Woo Commerce
        client.Logout();
        Console.WriteLine("Acumatica could not add specified entity: " + e);

        return null;
    }
}
```

URL for client address param: "https://mysandbox.acumatica.com/MyCompany/entity/Default/5.30.001"

The above code worked flawlessly for the previous version I was using but now when using this code with v6.1, I am getting an unauthorized 401 response at the client.LoginAsync() method.  Here is the error response:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Basic'.

I thought the upgraded versions were built to be backwards compatible so shouldn't this still be working?  Do I need to change something in order to have this work on v6.1?

From the [Acumatica Documentation](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(11))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1a9d6f7e-8546-426b-b1ff-d712fbcfbc7b):

> You can use the same system endpoint in future versions of Acumatica
>   ERP. For example, if you use the system endpoint with Version 5.30.001
>   and Contract Version 1 to access Acumatica ERP 5.3, you can use the
>   same endpoint to access future versions of Acumatica ERP.

P.S.  Eventually we will be upgrading to the REST API that is now available but this needs to work in the meantime.

Comment: Have you switched from HTTP to HTTPS? This looks like a 'binding' error. You could also try regenerating the service reference.

Comment: I have been able to use this service reference with both http and https on v5.3.  I tried regenerating the service reference with the url to the v6.1 Acumatica instance but I'm still receiving the same 401 error.

Comment: What do you see when navigating with your browser to:
https://mysandbox.acumatica.com/MyCompany/entity/Default/5.30.001

Comment: I get a 404 not found (after replacing with my actual values in your url). I just reverted all of my changes after trying updating the service reference and put it back to the original way I had it and now it is working!  I'm not sure what the issue was.

Comment: WebService API and reference in .Net are fickle, when experiencing connection issue it's sometimes necessary to rebuild reference from scratch.

Comment: Ok yes it could be that rebuilding it is what made it work again.  If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, WebService API and reference in .Net are fickle.

When experiencing connection issue it's sometimes necessary to Update or Rebuild reference from scratch:

[image]

In the same menu, you can get the WSDL address in 'Configure Service Reference':
[image]

Make sure that WSDL URL is accessible from a browser:
[image]